# PHP search doesn't work?

Tags: php, search, web, html

I am trying to create a search algorithm for my website but it doesn't work. It should show the title of an entry when what is searched is inside the title it gets from json files in a folder on the site. My HTML body in search.php:

```
<body>
<p>Your search: <script type="text/plain" style="display: inline;"><?php
                $query = $_GET['q'];
                echo $query;
                ?></script>

</p>
<p>Results: <?php
                $files = array();
                foreach (glob("jsons/*.json") as $file) {
                  $files[] = $file;
                }

                //echo($files[0]);

                foreach ($files as $file) {
                    $content = file_get_contents($file);
                    $json = json_decode($content);
                    $title = $json->title;
                    //echo 'x'.$title;
                    if (strpos("x".$title,$query !== false)) {
                       echo $title;
                    }
                }
            ?></p>
</body>
```

The file structure:

```
root
  jsons
    test.json
  index.html
  search.php
```

The content of test.json:

```
{
    "title": "Test",
    "text": "I am a test",
    "attachment": "test.txt"
}
```

The URL: `http://example.com/path/to/page/search.php?q=Test`

What I get when accessing the page:

```
Your search: Test

Results:
```

What it should return:

```
Your search: Test

Results:
Test
```

Does anyone here know why it doesn't find it or does anyone know a easier way?

Comment: `if (strpos("x".$title,$query !== false))` that line is all sorts of messy. Why `"x".`? Also, a bracket is in the wrong place.

Comment: `if (strpos("x".$title,$query) !== false)`

Comment: @JonStirling On a website it said that you should add "[some character]". to the thing it searches in

Comment: @Danny Thank you, sorry that I make beginner mistakes. I'm new to PHP